Any reason not to ask for breathalyzer test?
Assume Rob is stopped for suspicion of OWI / DUI and has not been drinking for 1 month nor used any pharmaceuticals or drugs.  In other words Rob is "clean".  Rob is elderly and has a neurological condition that affects balance, but not his ability to drive.
UPDATE/CLARIFICATION:
Assume that Rob's neurological condition doesn't significantly impair his ability to drive, but might make it unlikely for him to pass a field sobriety test (e.g. walking a straight line).
A breathalyzer is a quick test.  Rob seeks to end the stop as quickly / favorably.  Is there any reason not to ask for a breathalyzer and ask to be permitted to move on?
The link indicates that a BAC measurement between .05 and .08 can result in subsequent testing (Urine / Field motor), however, my blood is reserved (and mandatory) for cases of bodily injury.

Two things I might wonder: (1) what is the false positive rate for breathalyzer tests?  (2) Even if the breathalyzer test is negative, that isn't any guarantee that Rob will be let go, is it?  The officer might suspect Rob is under the influence of some substance other than alcohol, which the breathalyzer would not detect.

Any reason for driving while being unfit to drive is a crime. If Bob has a neurological condition that renders him unfit to control a vehicle, or perhaps a prescribed medication ditto, then he is unfit to drive. In UK, it seems that driving while impaired by a prescribed medication is a different matter from an unprescribed medication, whether or not it impairs the driving ability. I took an over-the-counter blue & orange night & day pill remedy. By the third morning I could hardly function, but was it legal to drive?

@WeatherVane: I think we're to assume here that Rob's condition doesn't significantly impair his ability to drive, but might make it hard for him to pass a field sobriety test (e.g. walking a straight line).

@NateEldredge my comment overlooked the "nor used any pharmaceuticals or drugs". But if Bob's sense of balance is affected, then his ability to sense the motion of the vehicle is impaired, and failing the walking test might indicate unfitness to drive.

@WeatherVane: "Any reason for driving while being unfit to drive is a crime."  Citation for Florida?  At an initial search, I couldn't find any such provision.

@NateEldredge in Florida, if an elderly person has lost their oxygen bottle, and been shot and wounded, and had a leg bitten off by an alligator, is there a law that renders them unfit to drive? The walking test might be good.

Depends what you mean by “breathalyzer.” In some states, a handheld fuel cell unit (preliminary breath test) is not admissible beyond probable cause, a larger IR spectrometer with calibration gas or blood draw is necessary for a conviction. Other states, the handheld unit is admissible.

The question is tagged Florida, which use a machine to measure alcohol in the breath.

@WeatherVane this is a hypothetical.  The assumption is that there exists at least one person with a condition that makes it difficult or impossible to walk in a straight line without impairing the ability to drive an automobile.  Whether such people actually exist is irrelevant to the hypothetical.  But I bet they do.  For example, people with cerebral palsy can have a gait that would make passing a straight line test very unlikely, yet they can drive.  The neuromuscular requirements to push pedals in and out are far less complicated than those of walking.

@WeatherVane "Any reason for driving while being unfit to drive is a crime": I just looked through the Florida traffic code and did not notice anything that would prohibit driving while impaired by, for example, a concussion.  Did I overlook something?  What section of which traffic code did you have in mind?

@gatorback You don't understand. Florida is one of those states where PBTs are not admissible beyond probable cause. A trunk/trailer-mounted DataMaster and handheld unit are different in court. "Machine to measure alcohol in the breath" is not sufficient information.

@user71659.  My understanding is confined to LE officers using a device to measure alcohol in the breath.    Please simplify the point your are trying to make.  Thanks

@gatorback Simplified: If you blow into the wrong machine and there's a mistake or malfunction, you're screwed. As I said multiple times, there's two different types of machine. Which one it is matters.
